# How to add an "int" to a "float" in the B programming language?

Tags: history, programming

C has data types, so if you add an `int` to a `float`, for example:

```
int i = 1;
float f = 2.5;
float r = i + f;
```

The C compiler will know that it should generate machine instructions that adds an `int` to a `float` because the C compiler can see that `i` is an `int` and `f` is a `float`.

---

But there is no data types in the B programming language, so if we did the following (not sure if this is a correct syntax):

```
auto i = 1;
auto f = 2.5;
auto r = i + f;
```

How would the B compiler know that it should generate machine instructions that adds an `int` to a `float`?

Comment: Do  you have a reference that says constants can be formed using a decimal point?  The grammar (https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/kbman.html) I'm looking at doesn't allow . in numbers, which tells me that B doesn't have a notion of floating point types.

Comment: @Erik Eidt Oh! sorry, I assumed that `float` literals are supported.

Comment: As a general observation, if the language is typeless, then an operator-symbol denotes a single operation (where in a typed language '+' for example denotes a number of different-but-similar operations), and it devolves to the programmer to select the appropriate operator to achieve his desired effect.

Answer (score 14):

B was a typeless language so `i + f` was always an integer addition operation.  As it was typeless this also means the value in `f` wouldn't be converted to integer, it was just assumed to already be an integer. The bits stored in `f` would give it its value.

However the original B implementation didn't support floating point, so there was no way to even have floating point literals.  There was at least one [implementation of B, for GCOS8](https://www.thinkage.ca/gcos/expl/b/manu/manu.html), where you could in fact do `f = 2.5;`, but `i + f` still worked as described above.  If you wanted to do a floating point addition instead you'd do `i #+ f`, but that had the same problem.  It assumed `i` was already a floating point value and wouldn't convert it.

So to get the same behaviour as in C, in addition to using the `#+` floating point addition operator, you'd have to explicitly convert `i` to a floating point value:

```
auto r;
r = #i #+ f;
```

Where `#` is the unary operator that converts integer values to floating point. B also doesn't seem to have supported initialization of auto variables, so two statements are necessary here.

Comment: So, is `i #+ f` basically equivalent to C's `*(float*)&i + *(float*)&f`?

Comment: @Ruslan Yah, it ignores whatever types `i` and `f` have, because B doesn't have types, and just interprets `i` and `f` as containing floating point values.